# Wrong data in bootstrap-table with Symfony 6.3.0

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table, symfony6

I needed bootstrap-table to display my database data in a table, but when refreshing the page, I see the right data then it is changed to other data

Here's my template.html.twig :

```
<table id="table" data-toolbar="#toolbar" data-pagination="true" data-page-size="25" data-search="true" data-show-export="true" data-toggle="table" data-click-to-select="true" data-search-align="left" data-show-columns="true" class="table table-list table-bordered table-striped m-auto">
    <thead>
        <tr>
        <th data-field="id" data-sortable="true" scope="col">N°</th>
        <th data-field="adresse" data-sortable="true" scope="col">Adresse</th>
        <th data-field="cp" data-sortable="true" scope="col">CP</th>
        <th data-field="ville" data-sortable="true" scope="col">Ville</th>
        <th data-field="refProprio" data-sortable="true" scope="col">Référence Propriétaire</th>
        <th data-field="date" data-sortable="true" scope="col">Date de l'Enquête</th>
        <th data-field="intermediaire" data-sortable="true" scope="col">Intermédiaire</th>
        <th data-field="suiviPar" data-sortable="true" scope="col">Responsable du Dossier</th>
        <th data-field="description" data-sortable="true" scope="col">Description</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-group-divider">
        {% for immeuble in immeubles %}
        <tr>
            <th>{{ immeuble.IDImmeuble }}</th>
        <th>{{ immeuble.Adresse }}</th>
        <th>{{ immeuble.CP }}</th>
        <th>{{ immeuble.Ville }}</th>
        <th>{{ immeuble.ReferenceProprio }}</th>
        <th>{{ immeuble.DateEnquete|date("d/m/Y") }}</th>
        <th>{{ immeuble.Intermediaire }}</th>
        <th>{{ immeuble.SuiviPar }}</th>
        <th>{{ immeuble.Description }}</th>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And my js file :

```
$(function () {
  $("#toolbar")
    .find("select")
    .change(function () {
      $("#table")
        .bootstrapTable("destroy")
        .bootstrapTable({
          exportDataType: $(this).val(),
          exportTypes: ["csv", "excel"],
          columns: [
            {
              field: "state",
              checkbox: true,
              visible: $(this).val() === "selected",
            },
            {
              field: "id",
              title: "ID",
            },
            {
              field: "description",
              title: "Description",
            },
            {
              field: "referenceProprio",
              title: "Référence Propriétaire",
            },
            {
              field: "vendu",
              title: "Vendu",
            },
          ],
        });
    })
    .trigger("change");
});
```

[And here is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qWroE.png)

I don't understand why the data in the table are old  values.

Can you help me?

I tried to change the name of the `data-field` but it didn't work.